# How to input stream by cin for more than 2 variable

Tags: c++

I have problem with C++ streams. I need to input some digits and program should compare that "strings" and mark as "const" "grove" etc. Main problem how to input those digits when i don't know how many user want to enter. I think the best idea is using -1 as last "identifier" of end. But how to input those digits one by one (digit1[space]digit2[space]digit3[space]-1)? I try to do that

```
int main() {

    int repeatCount = 0;
    int stringCount = 0;
    float digit1 = 0;
    float digit2 = 0;

    cout << "How many strings You have?" << endl;
    cin >> iloscPowtorzen;

    while(stringCount != repeatCount)
    {
        cin >> digit2 >> digit2;
        while (digit2 != -1)
        {
            //HERE I HAVEN'T GOT ANY IDEA
        }
        stringCount++;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Example (how should it work):

Input

```
<<How many strings You have?
>>3
>>1 1 1 1 -1
>>1 2 3 4 -1
>>4 3 2 1 -1
```

Output

```
<<const
<<grove
<<decrease
```

Sorry for my English. 
Regards

Comment: What is `iloscPowtorzen`? Should that be `repeatCount`?

Answer (score 0):

The first off thing off my mind:

1. Read the entire line as a string.
2. Use `strtok` with whitespace as delimiter.
3. `strtok` will return each number in string form, call `atoi` on each input.

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works and you don't need to enter "-1" or anything at the end. Just enter space separated numbers, hit enter and you are done (Intuitive way of giving input).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (true)
{
  float curNum;
  cin >> curNum;
  if (!cin)
    break;
  // do your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read them one at a time, not in pairs. Otherwise, it will read the first number on the next line into the second variable.

```
for (stringCount = 0; stringCount < repeatCount; stringCount++) {
    while (true) {
        cin >> digit2;
        if (digit2 == -1) {
            break; // get out of while loop
        }
        cin >> digit1;
        // do stuff with digit1 and digit2
    }
}
```